# How to define custom loss function with multi-outputs in tf-keras?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I want train a model of multi-outputs, named ctr(click through rate) and cvr in tensoflow keras.
The output should be ctr and cvr. But the loss should be ctr-loss and (ctr * cvr)-loss.
So, if click-label is zero, the (ctr*cvr)-loss should be zero.

```py
d = concatenate(inp_embed, axis=-1, name='concat') #Embeddings共享
d = Flatten()(d)

d_ctr = BatchNormalization()(d)
d_ctr = Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01))(d_ctr)
d_ctr = BatchNormalization()(d_ctr)
d_ctr = Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01))(d_ctr)
d_ctr = Dense(1, activation=activation)(d_ctr)

d_cvr = BatchNormalization()(d)
d_cvr = Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01))(d_cvr)
d_cvr = BatchNormalization()(d_cvr)
d_cvr = Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01))(d_cvr)
d_cvr = Dense(1, activation=activation)(d_cvr)

d_ivr = multiply([d_ctr, d_cvr])
deep = Model(inputs=inp_layer, outputs=[d_ctr, d_cvr])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a custom loss from multiple outputs :

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

             ctr_loss = losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, d_ctr)
             cvr_loss = losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, d_cvr)

             return ctr_loss * cvr_loss
```

And how to use it :

```
deep.compile(optimizer = sgd , loss = custom_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Feel free to add comments so that i can precise my answer.

Comment: This use the same y_true for ctr and cvr?  
But in fact, d_ctr and d_cvr has different y_true.

Comment: cvr_loss was only non-zero when click_label is not zero.

Comment: Ok, can you please update your answers with all this precisions ? What exactly do you want, and what do you have ?